# How can I check if a revision is present on a git remote

Tags: git

Is there a way that I can check if a revision is present on a remote without cloning the whole repo e.g.

```
git revispresent <remote> <sha1>
```

Where the return code is 0 if present, nonzero otherwise.

If I know it is the head of a branch then I can do:

```
git ls-remote <remote> -h <branch> | grep <sha1>
```

Is there a way to do this for any commit?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

```
git config --global alias.ls  log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

and run `git ls` whenever you want to .

it will show you all the commits that are present along with remote and the branch.

Comment: The question is about remote repo and `git log` can only be run in local.

Comment: it would give till what commits are in remotes. Please try.